# Changing Breeds: How to tell if breeds are actually changing?

Tags: netlogo

This is my code to switch breeds. How can I tell if the agents are changing breeds. I have a monitor that counts but the number is not changing. It is supposed to count passives vs. actives which should be changing.

```
to switch-A
  ask managers-A
  with [Rhat-A < mean-Rhat-P] [set breed managers-P]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

That code looks fine. What does the code box in the monitor have? I assume you are counting As in one monitor and Ps in another.

If nothing's happening, it's likely that you either never call the switch-A procedure, or that there aren't any A's that meet the condition. Try this:

```
to switch-A
  type "As with low value:" print count managers-A with [Rhat-A < mean-Rhat-P]
  ask managers-A with [Rhat-A < mean-Rhat-P]
  [ set breed managers-P
  ]
end
```

If you don't get output then it's not being called. If the count is 0 then you know to find out the values that are being tested etc.